# Lua - pcall with "entry point"

Tags: c, lua

I am loading Lua script with:

```
lua_State * L = lua_open();
luaL_openlibs(L);

const char lua_script[] = "function sum(a, b) return a+b; end print(\"_lua_\")";
int load_stat = luaL_loadbuffer(L,lua_script,strlen(lua_script),lua_script);
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
```

Now I can call

```
lua_getglobal(L,"sum");
```

and get result from it on C-side

However, when I call `lua_pcall`, script is executed and it leads to output "***_lua_***" to console. Without `lua_pcall`, I cannot later access `lua_getglobal`. Is there any way around this? I dont want to call `lua_pcall` before setting "entry point" function via `lua_getglobal`.

Comment: Redefine `print` temporarily to hide messages while executing `lua_pcall`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can modify the script, a different approach to this is to pack your initialization code (the `print` and whatever else may be there) into a separate function, like so:

```
lua_State * L = lua_open();
luaL_openlibs(L);

const char lua_script[] = "function sum(a,b) return a+b end return function() print'_lua_' end";
int load_stat = luaL_loadbuffer(L,lua_script,strlen(lua_script),lua_script);
lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0); // run the string, defining the function(s)…
// also puts the returned init function onto the stack, which you could just leave
// there, save somewhere else for later use, … then do whatever you need, e.g.
   /* begin other stuff */
   lua_getglobal(L, "sum");
   lua_pushinteger( L, 2 );
   lua_pushinteger( L, 3 );
   lua_pcall(L, 2, 1, 0);
   printf( "2+3=%d\n", lua_tointeger(L,-1) );
   lua_pop(L, 1);
   /* end other stuff (keep stack balanced!) */
// and then run the init code:
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0); // prints "_lua_"
```

Now, while you still have to run the chunk to define the function(s), the other initialization code is returned as a function which you can run at a later time / with a modified environment / … (or not at all, if it's unnecessary in your case.)

Comment: Similar idea: insert `coroutine.yield()` after `function sum() ... end` and use this chunk as a coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

The function `sum` is not defined until you run the script because function definition is an assignment in Lua, and it needs to be executed.

So, there is no way to avoid running the script that defines `sum`. That is what `lua_pcall` does. You could use `lua_call`, but then you wouldn't be able to handle errors.